# VBA Delete duplicate value and retain the last one

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete all the duplicate except for the one with largest order.
When I run the codes the first time, it delete 1,3,5,7,9,...,odd one
When I run second time it delete 2,4,6...
I just want to run 01 time and it delete all and retain the last one.
Please help me to fix my codes.

```vb
Sub Delete()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, lCol)).Select
    For i = 1 To lRow
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value And Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> 0 Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image: IMG1]

Answer (score 1):

Change

`For i = 1 To lRow`

to

`For i = lRow To 1 Step -1`

Comment: + For stepping backwards, however there are some more adjustments needed to make things work here =). OP is checking cells **ahead**.

Comment: @JvdV Yeah, it's assumed 

Comment: Please tell me more, which should be adjusted?